# How can I put separate images together to create an animation on Blender?

Tags: animation

I am using blender and editing a youtube intro and I have every frame separately rendered on to a folder in my folder. Ive also rendered as xVid. How do I put the separate images together to create an animation? This is what I have.[image]

Comment: go to the blender's VSE, press SHIFT+A  then I select all your photos by clicking and dragging and press add image strip. Also, make sure you set the fps to the same as the rendered photos

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch into Video Editing layout and focus on Video Sequence Editor.
2. Press Shift+A -> Image (or select Add -> Image from the menu bar).
3. Select all images you want to create the video from.
4. The video strip based on the image sequence will be automatically created.

Then you can of course render it to a regular video format.

Comment: Glad I could help :) You can set the answer as "accepted".